# Force typescript to put methods on the instance not the prototype

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to force typescript to put methods on the instance not the prototype. I ask this because I frequently have "this" scope issues which having methods on the prototype causes issues with.

Edit

---

For example in the output from the ts it seems inconsistent, I keeps the FooAlert in the FooViewModel function but the method openFooAlertDialogueAdd in the prototype

Js

```
var FooViewModel = (function () {
    function FooViewModel (json) {
        this.Foolert = ko.observable();

    }
    FooViewModel.prototype.openFooAlertDialogueAdd = function () {
        this.FooAlert = something;
    };
```

Ts

```
class FooViewModel{
     FooAlert = KnockoutObservableAny

      constructor(){
         this.FooAlert = ko.observable();
       }
     openFooAlertDialogueAdd() {
        this.FooAlert = something;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 18):

**If you're having scope issues I feel bad for you son, I've got 99 problems but `this` ain't one!**

Steve's answers show the correct way to define class methods, methods that will be exposed on each instance. However, if you're encountering scope issues, this is probably due to the fact you're calling those methods from another context.

For example, if you're using Knockout and you bind one of those methods to a `click` binding, Knockout will override the scope to the current scope of the binding, NOT the scope you have defined the method on.

There are two options to prevent this loss of scope.

Firstly you can define your methods in the constructor, to expose them on the instance instead of on the prototype.

Like:

```
class Greeter {
    greet:() => string;
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
        this.greet = () => {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        }
    }
```

Secondly, you could use the `=>` syntax to scope your class methods.

Example:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor() {
        this.greeting: "Blabla";
    }
    greet= () => {
        alert(this.greeting);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the comment about knockout changing the scope. could not figure out what was wrong.

Comment: are there not a way to tell knockout to not do it? I would like to define my methods outsite the constructor as it looks nicer :)

Comment: @s093294 AFAIK there's one other way which would only work with click handlers. You can use `ko.contextFor(event.target).$root` to get the root scope of the item you just clicked.

Comment: @basarat thanks for letting us know and update the answer. Great this feature is finally supported!

Comment: I came across this problem when using callbacks()` in jQuery and I needed to use the `() => ` syntax to make sure I was adding a callback to that instance and not some prototype reference. I initially tried `callback.add($.proxy(this.methodName))` but that's awkward and I couldn't find out how to de-register it anyway

Answer (score 5):

The methods on the prototype *are* the methods that are available on each instance.

```
class Example {
    constructor(private someProperty: string) {

    }

    method() {
        return this.someProperty;
    }
}

var exampleA = new Example('A');
var exampleB = new Example('B');
var exampleC = new Example('C');

console.log(exampleA.method()); // A
console.log(exampleB.method()); // B
console.log(exampleC.method()); // C
```

Each instance will have the `someProperty` and `method()` copied to its prototype. You can check this using:

```
alert(exampleC.hasOwnProperty('someProperty') ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

It is only when the instance doesn't have its own property that JavaScript will walk up any dependency chain to find the property on a class higher up the dependency chain.

If you supply the code where you are having trouble with the scope of `this` I'm sure we can help you to fix it.

Comment: I guess I have to do  openFooAlertDialogueAdd = function etc as that gives the correct Js output

Comment: Put the output JS to one side for a moment - because I don't think that matters - can you show an example of the scope problem? i.e. I think you want to solve the problem my making things static, but I think there is likely to be a better way. The static fix is to prepend the static keyword: `static openFooAlertDialogueAdd() ...`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a TypeScript/Knockout issue, as @Anzeo pointed out in his answer as well as your edit. I've gotten around the issue by putting my method declarations in the constructor but also using the `var self = this;` convention pointed out in the "Managing 'this'" section on [Knockout's Computed Observable documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). You TS code could look like this:

```
class FooViewModel{
    FooAlert: KnockoutObservableAny;
    openFooAlertDialogueAdd: () => void;

    constructor(){
        var self = this;
        self.FooAlert = ko.observable();
        self.openFooAlertDialogueAdd = function(){
            self.FooAlert('whatever your FooAlert observable takes');
        };
    }
}
```

No matter what scope change might occur, the JavaScript closure around `self` keeps you from having to worry about `this` changing. That should solve both your problems.

Comment: Using `=>` (the arrow or lambda function) will take this scope copy for you so you do not need to copy it yourself.

Comment: @Anzeo, That it will! Thanks for pointing that out. I think I still prefer the explicit copy with the self convention. It does clutter up the constructor, however, so I might look into using the lambda more.