# TypeScript method type signature redundant

Tags: methods, lambda, typescript, signature, tslint

Maybe I'm seriously missing something, but I'm unable to get rid of a syntax problem with all my classes.

Here is an example :

```
class Foo {
   bar: (x: string, y: number) => string = (xx: string, yy: number) : string => {
      // do some stuff...
   };
}
```

Since I'm enforcing type declarations using tslint, ALL my methods are written like this. It's horrible. Having to copy paste the arguments part, renaming the args names between the type declaration and the lambda declaration is soooo painfull.

So : is there a better way to combine type signature and lambda declaration without all the knee jerking ? I sincerely hope I have missed something and hope this is not "by design" ! :)

Comment: so writing `var bar = (x: string, y : number) : string =>{ /*dostuff*/};` is not valid according to tslint?

Comment: This is incorrect : you cannot declare a method with the keyword 'var'.

Comment: ops, sorry, but without the `var` then, will that cause tslint to complain?

Comment: Absolutely : expected member-variable-declaration: 'bar' to have a typedef

Comment: "Since I'm enforcing type declarations using tslint" ... this is like complaining that your alarm clock keeps waking you up at 4 AM. If you don't like that, stop setting it for that time!

Comment: I'm a just wondering if this is the correct form or if I have missed something. If this is a side effect of a deliberate choice of design in the langage, then so be it, I will have to live with it and will have to adjust my "alarm clock" has you said.

Comment: It is *not* recommended to explicity declare all your types like that.  You can turn off "implicit any" and that will make sure that a non-any type can be infered.

Comment: I prefer @uosɐſ's idea the most. Enable the 'noImplicitAny" option of the TypeScript compiler and use it instead of the TSLint typedef rule.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure TSLint to enforce types but ignore the type of the functions:

> typedef enforces type definitions to exist. Rule options:
>
> - "call-signature" checks return type of functions
> - "parameter" checks type specifier of function parameters
> - "property-declaration" checks return types of interface properties
> - "variable-declaration" checks variable declarations
> - "member-variable-declaration" checks member variable declarations

You can use a file like [this one](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/docs/sample.tslint.json) to configure TSLint. And read [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) to learn more about how to configure it.

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/tslint.json) the config we use for TSLint itself. It's pretty reasonable, but I'd say don't hesitate at all in tweaking it. For example, I much prefer single quotes to double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

If you're targeting ES5, you can also do something like this:

```
var bar = (x: string, y: number) : string => {
  // do some stuff...
};

class Foo {
   get bar () { return bar; }
}

var test = (new Foo).bar('hello', 3);
```

Or:

```
class Foo {
   get bar () {
       return (xx: string, yy: number): string => {
            // do some stuff... 
       };
    }
}
```

This way the method's context is preserved and it also exists on the prototype. There's also no need to copy the argument types, TSC will infer them.

Comment: Had problems regarding the 'this' context several times. So I switched to the lambda assignment.

Comment: What are those problems?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335517/force-typescript-to-put-methods-on-the-instance-not-the-prototype

Comment: Okay, Knockout kills another one

Comment: Updated answer (15 char)

Comment: It's getting more and more verbose... ;) I don't want to have to write so much code because in TS, we must 'name' the arguments in the signature....